# How is the Tomcat temp directory location defined?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, directory, liferay, temp

I am running Tomcat bundled with Liferay5.2.3 and use Eclipse 3.5 (Galileo) as my IDE.  I set up my Tomcat server in Eclipse as per this blog entry: http://www.jroller.com/holy/entry/developing_portlets_for_liferay_in.  If I start Tomcat via the Eclipse server config, Liferay/Tomcat uses my C:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Temp\ directory.  However, if I start Tomcat directly using the startup.bat script, Liferay/Tomcat uses the Tomcat temp directory.  I can't figure out if Eclipse, Liferay or Tomcat is deciding which temp directory to use or how to change it.  I would prefer to use the Tomcat temp directory.

I have this issue with both the Lifera/Tomcat bundles 5.5 and 6.0 (liferay-portal-tomcat-6.0-5.2.3.zip and liferay-portal-tomcat-5.5-5.2.3.zip).

Anybody have any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you start Tomcat with catalina.sh (or catalina.bat), the temp directory is set with the CATALINA_TMPDIR variable:

```
if [ -z "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" ] ; then
# Define the java.io.tmpdir to use for Catalina
    CATALINA_TMPDIR="$CATALINA_BASE"/temp
fi
```

Also you can pass below as VM argument while starting Tomcat in Eclipse to use it as temp directory.

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir="C:\Program Files\liferay-portal-5.2.3-tomcat-6.0\tomcat-6.0.18\temp"
```

Answer (score 3):

Although I still don't know where/how Tomcat determines where the default temp directory should be, nor do I know why Eclipse sets it to something different, I have found out that you can set the temp directory via a VM argument when starting Tomcat in Eclipse:

-Djava.io.tmpdir="C:\Program Files\liferay-portal-5.2.3-tomcat-6.0\tomcat-6.0.18\temp"

Answer (score 1):

You can find the following folder structure in your workspace:

```
.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\
```

Here you will find the folder which is attached with tomcat in eclipse.