# Tomcat deployment failure

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins

### ***The Issue I'm Having***

I've implemented a mild change to my application, and I checked it into the subversion repository. Once that was checked in, I ran a Jenkins build. Jenkins is currently running on a Windows server.

The error I am receiving is the following:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal       
org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (deploy) on project sd-rest-servlet: 
Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: FAIL - Deployed application at context path /sd but 
context failed to start
```

I investigated further into this error message, so I checked out the Tomcat logs on the Jenkins server, and I found an underlying issue:

```
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\temp\28-sd does not exist or is not a readable directory
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4320)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4489)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1385)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1389)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1653)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1662)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1642)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Now, as I understand it, the `temp` folder is only ever used in this way when I set `antiJarLocking` or `antiResourceLocking` to `true` in the `context` file. However, as you can see, I have not included this in the `Context` element:

```
<Context unpackWAR="false">
```

### ***Other Behaviour***

**Unable to Undeploy**

After some close inspection, I've found that Jenkins isn't able to undeploy the application. In the logs, I see this message.

```
[INFO] Undeploying application at http://localhost:8082/sd
[INFO] OK - Undeployed application at context path /sd
```

However, the build fails when it attempts to deploy, with the following error:

```
Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: FAIL - Application already exists at path /sd
```

**Erratic access to the Temp directory**

I've also noticed that it throws the same `IllegalArgumentException` whenever it attempts to access any file inside the `temp` directory. This tells me there is something wrong with the `temp` directory, however I've set the permissions, and earlier on in the application, Jenkins actually puts a file in the `temp` directory.

**No Problems Depoying**

Jenkins actually deploys the application without a problem. I've watched the directories change when the files are added to them, including the `temp` directory. This tells me that Jenkins is randomly deciding it can't read the contents of the directory, despite the fact that it is added a file to it. It appears that it has write permissions, but not read permissions, which really doesn't make much sense!

### ***Attempts to Solve the problem***

**Ensured the file exists**

I first attempted to look inside `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\temp\28-sd` to see if the file existed. Sure enough, it existed.

**Altered Permissions**

I've set permissions to allow for full access from every user on the server, as a precaution.

**Researched the use of the Temp directory**

I've attempted to configure my context file to avoid all use of the `temp` directory, so I don't have a clue why it's still attempting to read from it. I am inexperienced with the ins and outs of this technology, so I may still have some settings that require the `temp` folder.

### ***Edits***

**Expanded Tomcat Logs**

```
18-Dec-2013 12:14:19 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/sd]
18-Dec-2013 12:16:06 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor sd.xml
18-Dec-2013 12:16:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart

<!-- Above stacktrace goes here -->

18-Dec-2013 12:16:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
18-Dec-2013 12:16:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
18-Dec-2013 12:16:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/sd] startup failed due to previous errors
18-Dec-2013 12:16:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext stop
INFO: Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/sd] has  not been started
```

**Some more information on the issue**

After reading through the logs for the thousandth time, I reread this line:

`...Tomcat 6.0\temp\28-sd does not exist or is *not a readable directory*`

So when I looked inside the `temp` directory again, I realized that the files being generated aren't `directories`. They are these weird file objects with no extension, and they look like this:

[image]

For me, this indicates that something has gone wrong with the way Tomcat manipulates files and this is the core of the issue. I hope this extra information helps someone with the answer!

Comment: Is this a problem with Jenkins or with your application deployed through Jenkins? There were some real bad windows bugs in the jenkins 1.540 to 1.544 series

Comment: I'm not sure if the issue lies solely with Jenkins, because it's successfully building similar projects. I think it's an issue surrounding my Tomcat instance.

Comment: Could you provide some more lines from the Tomcat log just before the `Error starting static Resources` line or maybe full Tomcat log from the beginning. It may contain a useful info about the causes of the error.

Comment: I have included the additional logs, surrounding the stack trace. In place of the stack trace I have inserted the comment `<!-- Above stacktrace goes here -->`

Comment: Those "wierd" files look like WAR files without the WAR extension.  What do the increasing numbers signify?   Is your Tomcat installed standlong, as a Windows services, or via Maven Cargo?  Would you be willing to switch to Maven Cargo to get around this?

Comment: Tomcat is installed as a Windows Service. I've already solved this issue by upgrading Tomcat to 7.0, but I would like to know what causes this issue. I found it to be really bizarre and it had me stumped for a while before I gave in and just ran a new install.

Comment: Sounds very similar to this old bug:https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43611

Comment: I saw similar problems when there are spaces in tomcat installation path. Try moving it to C:\dev\tomcat-6.0.x\

Comment: Hoaz. I think this may have been the problem. Good spot! Post this as an answer please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that Hoaz suggested moving the deployment out of `C:\Program Files\` because of the space character. I wonder if it's rather a permissions issue than the space in the name?

Can you please also try these (without uninstalling the Tomcat from `C:\Program Files\`):

1. Configure the location of the temp directory to be outside `C:\Program Files\`

   Reference : SO question [How is the Tomcat temp directory location defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837972/how-is-the-tomcat-temp-directory-location-defined)
2. Change the location of `docBase` and/or `appBase`

   Reference :Apache documentation http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html

Also, forcing the installation outside "C:\Program Files" would work fine unless / until someone insists that "That's where the Program Files should live, you know". :-)

Comment: Congratulations! Good answer. It turned out to be triggered by a problem with the space, and the subsequent issue was with permissions so you couldn't have been much more accurate.

Comment: Hurray! Thanks Chris!