# Why Tomcat 8 does not start in a container?

Tags: java, tomcat, configserver

I try to launch a container embedded Tomcat8 with Netflix's Configserver.
But for some reason I don't understand, tomcat refuses to start.

Here is the first part of the stack trace

```
 ______   ______   .__   __.  _______  __    _______      _______. _______ 
.______   ____    ____  _______ .______      
 /      | /  __  \  |  \ |  | |   ____||  |  /  _____|    /       ||   ____||   _  \  \   \  /   / |   ____||   _  \     
|  ,----'|  |  |  | |   \|  | |  |__   |  | |  |  __     |   (----`|  |__   |  |_)  |  \   \/   /  |  |__   |  |_)  |    
|  |     |  |  |  | |  . `  | |   __|  |  | |  | |_ |     \   \    |   __|  |      /    \      /   |   __|  |      /     
|  `----.|  `--'  | |  |\   | |  |     |  | |  |__| | .----)   |   |  |____ |  |\  \----.\    /    |  |____ |  |\  \----.
 \______| \______/  |__| \__| |__|     |__|  \______| |_______/    |_______|| _| `._____| \__/     |_______|| _| `._____|

Running Spring Boot Version ::  (v2.0.4.RELEASE)
2018-08-29 12:08:50.863  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.w.s.t.c.c.ServletInitializer           : The following profiles are active: default
2018-08-29 12:08:50.881  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5fc310b0: startup date [Wed Aug 29 12:08:50 UTC 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@f9b7ab1
2018-08-29 12:08:52.681  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=22fb1cdd-9c43-334c-a414-24f6536bb9f1
2018-08-29 12:08:52.702  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-08-29 12:08:52.840  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e9f24b7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-08-29 12:08:52.847  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1967 ms
29-Aug-2018 12:08:52.847 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-29 12:08:53.185  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-08-29 12:08:53.186  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-08-29 12:08:53.212  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@570445
2018-08-29 12:08:53.930  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.facto
ry.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository]: Factory method 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create temp dir
2018-08-29 12:08:53.939  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
29-Aug-2018 12:08:53.945 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/De
faultRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository]: Factory method 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create temp dir
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
```

I seriously don't understand what the problem is ...
Let me add that it worked well with the same execution conditions and Tomcat 7 ! I would really appreciate a few help, at least to understand this error and to try resolving it by myself !
Thank you by advance for your help !

Comment: `Cannot create temp dir` looks like tomcat is not allowed to write on your server

Comment: It runs as root user all the time !

Comment: "nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create temp dir" => Obvious, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't modify any permission while upgrading from tomcat7 to tomcat8 ...

Answer (score -1):

TEMP folder can be manage through the way you run the server, just to be sure you can access that folder through a env var ?

[How is the Tomcat temp directory location defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837972/how-is-the-tomcat-temp-directory-location-defined)